# Sequence of discrete random variables converging almost surely to a uniform random variable

Tags: probability-theory

Does there exist a sequence of discrete random variables $X_{1},X_{2}...$ that converges almost surely to a random variable with uniform distribution on $[0,1]$?

Comment: what's a uniform random variable?

Comment: A random variable with a uniform distribution

Comment: Can't you just let $X_n$ be rounding down to the nearest $\frac{j}{n}$ in $[0,1]$ and $X$ be the identity on $[0,1]$? I'm confused why you're phrasing in terms of probability. You want a sequence of measurable functions with discrete range converging a.e. to the identity.

Comment: sorry, what is j?

Comment: $X_n : [0,1] \to [0,1]$. If $\frac{j}{n} \le x < \frac{j+1}{n}$ for some integer $0 \le j \le n-1$, then $X_n(x) := \frac{j}{n}$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $X\sim U(0,1)$ and consider $X_n=\lfloor nX\rfloor /n$.